# BigQuery issue with dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery

We are having issues with our dataprep jobs which use BigQuery as a datasource. I reached our to Alteryx and they are suggesting that this is a bigquery issue. Here is the email thread with their support team. We have checked the other options and they seem fine.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

---

Hello,

Thanks for sharing the details. Your help is invaluable in resolving the issue.

Can you confirm if JobGroup 20452148 is related to failing (ClientPayments) datasource?

For two failed job today I see same error as earlier. This seems to be a BigQuery issue:
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.card

Can you please try:
Access the BigQuery table (related ClientPayments) outside of Trifacta?
Access the above in BigQuery.
Check with your Google Admin as the error is internal to BigQuery.
Best
Rohit Jain
Alteryx Community: https://community.alteryx.com/

--------------- Original Message ---------------
From: Alteryx Support [support@alteryx.com]
Sent: 7/19/2023 2:31 PM

Subject: RE: Case #00640906 - Dataprep and BigQuery [ ref:_00DE0JJZ4._5003n2isLp8:ref ]

Hello,

Thanks for sharing the screenshot. We understand that you are facing an error while executing a flow on Dataflow. I will try to resolve the issue at the earliest.

In our logs I noticed error:
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.card

Can you please help with below to analyze the issue:
Share the Dataflow logs.
You get these by navigating to Trifacta Job (as in screenshot) > Click View Dataflow Job (you will be navigated to Google Cloud Console) > Select "Logs" on bottom left > Under "Job Logs" tab click "View in Logs Explorer" icon > Download logs.
Same for "Worker Logs"
Screenshot of any messages under "Diagnostics" tab
Run the same job on Photon and check if it is successful?
Clarify "affects several flows which utilize the same BigQuery recipe" as mentioned in your last mail? Was a copy of same recipe used in multiple flows?
Are you facing issue with one specific flow or with all flows which use the same BigQuery input? You can create a new flow with same BigQuery source and run the flow to test.
Are you facing issue for specific BigQuery source or all BigQuery sources/tables?
Create a simple flow with attached CSV as input and blank recipe. Run the flow on Photon and Dataflow. Please share back JobGroup IDs if you run into error.
Share a Flow Export .
Please let me know.
Best
Rohit Jain
Alteryx Community: https://community.alteryx.com/